# How to convert the negative integer to positive

Tags: java, netbeans, wampserver

```
String v1 = lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText();


int a = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText());

int b = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PRESENT_READ.getText());

int cm = a-b;

try{

    String sql = "UPDATE reading SET Cubic_meter=' "+cm+" ' WHERE Reading_Number=' "+v1+"' ";

    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    rs=ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}
```

This code display negative Cubic_meter column in my database, want to have a positive Cubic_meter even if the `jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText()` is lesser than `jLabel_PRESENT_READ.getText()`.

Comment: Unrelated to your positive/negative question, but as ChoChoPK points out, it's best to use parameterized queries, not string concatenation. Here's why: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might be looking for [`Math.abs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-):

> Returns the absolute value of an int value. If the argument is not negative, the argument is returned. If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.

(There are also versions for other types — `long`, `float`, `double`...)

There's an important caveat:

> Note that if the argument is equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the most negative representable int value, the result is that same value, which is negative.

Comment: please give me guide to how I will insert this to my code.
Thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: @JhaezzJohn: `int cm = Math.abs(a-b);`?

Answer (score 1):

Do Math.abs like T.J. Crowder suggested, but also do

catch NumberFormatException when parsing the input

Change your SQL statement to use bound variables, like this

```
    String sql = "UPDATE reading SET Cubic_meter=? WHERE Reading_Number= ?";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, cm); // assuming always positive
    ps.setInt(2, v1);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Using bound variable is a good practice to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: sir I follow your suggestion but know an exception occur saying: "No value specified for parameter 1 "

String sql = "Update reading set Cubic_meter=? where Reading_Number=?";
ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.executeUpdate();
ps.setInt(1, cm);
ps.setInt(2, v1);

Comment: You need to put executeUpdate last

Comment: How do i parse the NumberFormatException in my code sir

Comment: I got error on my code for using NumberFormatException: 
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, cm);
            ps.setInt(2, v1);
            ps.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this?

```
 value=value*-1; //simply multiply by -1.
```

You can also set a condition to check if the value is negative with an if statement such as.

```
 if(value<0)
   value=value*-1; //simply multiply by -1.
```

Comment: The solution offered by Mr. Crowder is great and shorter to implement. You can use it as `value=Math.abs(value);`. Either would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int cm = a-b;
int cm2 = cm*(-1);

try{

    String sql = "UPDATE reading SET Cubic_meter=' "+cm2+" ' WHERE Reading_Number=' "+v1+"' ";

    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    rs=ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}
```